# How to see what ads my visitors are seeing

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, tracking, saas

I have a website with Adsense.

I want to get a an idea for what ads my visitors are seeing. I am currently using a service that allows me to view site users actions, but this hides the ads, presumably it would create an invalid impression if they displayed the ad.

Is there a way to see the ads that my site visitors are seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that in most cases ads are delivered based on a person's search and browsing history, every person will likely see different ads at different times.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm trying to see. I imagine it should be possible to "add some javascript" and "get a photo" of the page the user brings up ... just not sure a) if it's possible 2) what the next step would be

Comment: You are missing the point.  The ads are generated dynamically for each visitor.  There is nothing "to see", you would have to fake all the data for the visitor you are trying to pretend to be and then figure the ad content networks top secret algorithm.  

As far as I know it can't be done.  Unless you were trying to game the system, why would you want to anyway?

Comment: The reason is to be able to identify whether the ads being shown are relevant to the content or not. I get ads that are totally related to me, but not the content, despite disabling contextual ads - and people have commented that the ads aren't relevant. I agree it can't be done, since there is no way to take a "snapshot/picture" of the screen - the only way to do this uses the DOM and that would not get the desired result, for reasons you suggest.

Comment: Ad delivery networks are not interested in ads that are relevant to the content, there is more likely someone will click if it is relevent to them personally.  Just relax and let the system do its thing, this doesn't seem to bother anyone else, dont let it bother you.

Comment: >> let the system do its thing
Yep, I guess will have to :) thanks for taking the time to answer + clarify